# Creating a wrapper around a compose binding and bind to the composed view model

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm looking to create a dashboard using aurelia which features a plugin-type framework to add new widgets to this dashboard. I'd like to wrap these widgets so I can show title and information which is outside the widget's control, so I'd like something like:

```html
<widget-wrapper widget-name="sales"></widget-wrapper>
```

and widget-wrapper would look like

```html
<template>
  <h3>${widget.title}</h3>

  <compose view-model.bind="widgetName"></compose>

  <span>${someOtherInfo}</span>
</template>
```

Then the author of the sales widget just needs a view which shows the main data and a viewmodel which defines a title property and then does whatever it needs to, to display the sales data.

I don't think the compose binding can be used here - as I won't be able to bind to the title.

I know I can specify a view for the compose binding but this doesn't help either, as I do want to use the default.

I read about template parts but it seems this is in the wrong direction for my needs - the widget-wrapper here would define what should be replaced, and the replaceable part would need to be in the sales widget. And I'd also still be stuck when trying to get the widget's title.

Is there some aurelia templating feature I've missed that would support such a scenario?

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/composition-aurelia-report-builder/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind to the compose element's current view model.

Here's an example: https://gist.run?id=c28ed9f1e893cc3efd5a

**app.html**

```html
<template>
  <require from="./widget-wrapper"></require>

  <widget-wrapper module-name="foo"></widget-wrapper>
</template>
```

**app.js**

```js
export class App {
}
```

**foo.html**

```html
<template>
  ${message}
</template>
```

**foo.js**

```js
export class Foo {
  name = 'my name is foo';
  message = 'hello world!';
}
```

**widget-wrapper.html**

```html
<template>
  <h1>${composeViewModel.currentViewModel.name}</h1>
  <compose view-model.ref="composeViewModel" view-model.bind="moduleName"></compose>
</template>
```

**widget-wrapper.js**

```js
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class WidgetWrapper {
  @bindable moduleName;

  bind() {
    console.log(this.composeController);
  }
}
```

Comment: That's perfect! I had seen the ref binding before, but had only seen it used with HTML elements. Learned another new thing in aurelia.. thanks.